# DualLink DVI-D to DisplayPort

Tags: dvi, displayport, video-conversion

I have a Dell 3007WFP monitor which features only DualLink DVI-D for video input. The computer I am trying to connect it to only features VGA, DisplayPort, and SingleLink DVI-D (via a docking station). The built-in DisplayPort supports up to my maximum resolution of 2560x1600, meanwhile the VGA and SingleLink DVI-D connections are insufficient.

I found [the following device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ISVI3U) which purports to be capable of converting a DualLink DVI-D signal to DisplayPort. Will this converter indeed work to connect a DualLink DVI-D monitor output to the DisplayPort input on my computer at maximum resolution?

[image: DualLink DVI-D to DisplayPort Adapter]

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: @MarkSzymanski Not a shopping question. I'm asking if it would do what I need. I don't want to buy it if it won't work.

Comment: @MarkSzymanski this isn't a shopping recommendation per se, he's asking if the given product will work for his computer.

Comment: Agreed, this is a functionality question - "Is this the right sort of device to do this with" not "Which one should I buy", which isn't really a shopping recommendation, anymore than saying "What do I need to buy to program EEPROM chips with?" is a shopping recommendation.  ("Which programmer should I buy?" would be one, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  Almost every video card on the market needs a powered converter to get dual-link DVI working with DisplayPort (this is not true for single-link DVI).  Note that COULD potentially be different for your exact graphics (which you don't mention), it's just EXTREMELY unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This confirms what Dell support told me as well. The video adapter I am using is a NVIDIA NVS 3100M which does support up to 2560x1600.